# ubuntu 18.10 broken for a lot of packages? This time libdouble-conversion?

Tags: apt, 18.10, shared-library

While trying to install my usual environment on Ubuntu 18.10 I have run into many, many problems.

I am curious why packages that are supposedly working under 18 seem to have all these issues?

I managed to build emacs from source, so my problems with emacs-gtk/emacs-common/emacs26 can all be put on the back burner.

But clementine and simplescreenrecorder both install using apt install and both, when run complain about

error while loading shared libraries: libdouble-conversion.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libdouble-conversion-dev is already the newest version (2.0.1-5).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.

From what I can see, there is a symbolic link:

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     25 Apr 10  2018 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdouble-conversion.so -> libdouble-conversion.so.1
```

to a nonexistent file libdouble-conversion.so.1

```
apt-cache policy libdouble-conversion1
libdouble-conversion1:
  Installed: 2.0.1-5
  Candidate: 2.0.1-5
  Version table:
 *** 2.0.1-5 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I also built libdouble-conversion manually, but it creates /usr/local/lib/libdouble-conversion.so.3 and clementine, simplescreenrecorder, and octave are all expecting .so.1

I deleted libdouble-conversion is /usr/local/lib and tried:

sudo apt install --reinstall libdouble-conversion1

now octave, simplescreenrecorder and clementine all coredump.
Is there any way to identify what is happening? To show which shared library is failing? I would like to show that it is in fact, still libdouble-conversion.

I would of course like to solve this problem, but I would also appreciate if anyone could explain why there are so many problems like this with 18.10?

Comment: What do you mean by "packages that are supposedly working under 18"? In particular, note that 18.04 and 18.10 are different.

Comment: It's better if you're specific.  Ubuntu 18 could mean (1)  Ubuntu Core 18, (2) Ubuntu 18.04 LTS [2018.April release] & (3) Ubuntu 18.10 [2018.October release].  Going by name, Ubuntu Core 18 (the IoT Ubuntu) is probably the closest

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy libdouble-conversion1` to your question.

Comment: @Florian Diesch: done

Comment: I don't have this problem on my 18.10 system. If `libdouble-conversion.so.1` is not there, you must have deleted it, knowingly or not. You can reinstall the package with `sudo apt install --reinstall libdouble-conversion1`.

Comment: The only thing I did was sudo apt install packages, and when they did not work, sometimes remove them because they stopped other packages from installing. For example, with emacs-gtk failing, other packages could not be installed.  Doing an apt remove was the only way to get it unstuck. I did the reinstall just now, and octave, simplescreenrecorder, and clementine all crash.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (program not running on 20.04) where the .so.1 file is not available.

I solved with:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdouble-conversion.so.3 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdouble-conversion.so.1
```

After that the program run just fine. Might also be the case for you.